# cannot print a string from a vector of strings

Tags: string, vector, c++14, cout

I have a vector of strings, and I fill the first string in it manually character by character

```
vector <std::string>  vec(6);
vec[0][0] = 'h';
vec[0][1] = 'e';
vec[0][2] = 'y';
cout << "vec[0] = " << vec[0] << "\n"
```

now I want to print the vec[0] which is supposed to be a string `"hey"` , but it prints empty space.
I can print only if I print it character by character also, like this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<1 ; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0 ; j < 3 ; j++)
       {
           cout << vec[i][j];
       }
       cout << "\n";
   }
```

Why I can't simply print the string as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector <std::string>  vec(6);` gives you a vector of six empty strings.  `vec[0][0] = 'h';` is trying to assign the character `h` into the first slot of the first empty string, which is not legal, as the bracket operator can only replace existing characters.   Use something like `vec[0] += 'h'` to append to the string.

Comment: But it actually succeeded in assigning the character 'h' into the first slot of the first empty string, as it prints it inside the `for loop` , is it not legal but working?